# There is any bug in the bluetooth android api?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In my company we are trying to use the official bluetooth api of Android to switch on the bluetooth and use it. But we have found several problems with different phones.

The thing is that in some of them it works perfectly and in some others it doesn't work at all. For example:

- HTC MAGIC 2.1 Works
- HTC LEGEND 2.1 Doesn't work.
- HTC LEGEND 2.2 Doesn't work
- NEXUS ONE 2.2 Works
- T-mobile myTouch 3G Slide 2.1 Doesn't Works

So my questions are:

There is any way to make it work in any device? A software solution.

Is a hardware related problem? We can't do anything about it.

How this people (Bluetooth File Transfer) make it work in any device? (at least the ones we tested) Could be them using some low level calls or something similar?

I've been researching in the web  but I didn't find anything conclusive. We are using the api like the boys of Android says [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)

I hope somebody give us some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

At least I can confirm that it's not working on Acer liquid and some force close exceptions appreas.

AFAIK, It's not hardware problem, but it's the vendor problem and its build, in my case it's Acer.

If you ask me to imagen a solution right now, well, I'd say you should fix it and build a new rom, which is time consuming and I don't think it's very useful in your case, since you can't fix that in all people phones.

I hope some other people can answer better.

-Rami